# Why does my page leak memory from using jQuery's replaceWith?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I don't do a whole lot of JavaScript, so I'm afraid this might be a really stupid question, but I've been googling around a fair lot, and while I've found quite a bit about memory leaks with jQuery, nothing seems to match my situation.

Basically, I have a page where I'm continually replacing content with newly downloaded content. To do this, I'm using jQuery's `replaceWith` function, passing the downloaded HTML fragment as a string. The whole page is a bit complex and takes some time to leak significant amounts of memory, but I've reproduced the memory leak with this simple HTML snippet:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var sequence = 1;
      function update() {
          $("#test").empty().replaceWith('<p id="test">Test ' + sequence++ + '</p>').remove();
          setTimeout(update, 1);
      }
      $(document).ready(update);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="test">Test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Viewing this page in Chromium seems to continually eat more and more memory, and I can't seem to figure out why. The `.empty()` and `.remove()` calls on the `replaceWith()` line weren't there originally, but I threw them in since they were commonly suggested as fixes to DOM replacement memory leaks. Seemingly to no effect, however.

Comment: Out of interest, if you run the script in several browser tabs simultaneously, is the leakage rate proportional to the number of tabs?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Depends on how you look at it. Tabs that aren't visible don't seem to be running the timeouts at all, so they don't leak either. Looking at the corresponding processes, however, each tab leaks independently.

Comment: Mmm, that's a bit inconclusive. I didn't know Chromium tabs behaved that way. I use Opera most of the time and I thought it behaved differently, but I'm wondering now ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your memory leak has something to do with the recursive nature of your setTimeout(...) function.

Try this instead:

```
var sequence = 1;
function update() {
      $("#test").empty().replaceWith('<p id="test">Test ' + sequence++ + '</p>').remove();
      var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        update();
      }, 1);
  }
$(document).ready(update);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Dolda2000 what are you measuring memory?  I'm using the 'memory monitor' chrome plugin and it seems to be showing pretty regular garbage collection.

Comment: I'm checking the RSS of the Chromium process (via `top`), and also Chromium's task manager window, and they agree that it's continuously increasing.

Comment: Your comment made me cross-check with Firefox, however, and it actually seems to not leak memory, which makes me wonder if this might in fact be a bug in Chromium. The leak has been present over many versions of Chromium, however, which had made me discard that as a possibility.

Comment: Actually, Firefox does seem to grow after all, it just grows much less "per update".

Comment: Then again, after a fair amount of time had passed, it seems like Firefox GC'd and memory usage is down again. I'll have to investigate this track.

Comment: this is interesting. It seems there is a pretty steady growth (about 100Kb instead of 1MB) even when I remove all DOM references.  The timer is definitely holding on to references to DOM objects and function pointers.